# Why GSL p-value for Pearson and Spearman are different from Python or R

Tags: correlation, p-value, pearson-r

I'm using [Pearson function of GSL library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/statistics.html#c.gsl_stats_correlation) in Rust, but I'm not getting the same value for the p-value that I'm getting in Python o R:

**Python**

```py
from scipy import stats

res = stats.pearsonr([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 9, 2.5, 6, 4])
print(res) // r = -0.7426106572325057 | p-value = 0.1505558088534455
```

**R**

```r
cor.test(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(10, 9, 2.5, 6, 4)) // r = -0.7426107 | p-value = 0.1506
```

**Rust (I'm using RGSL that is a binding of GSL for Rust)**

```rust
use rgsl::{randist::beta::beta_P, statistics::correlation};

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0];
    let y = vec![10.0, 9.0, 2.5, 6.0, 4.0];
    let n = x.len();
    let ab = (n / 2 - 1) as f64;
    let r = correlation(&x, 1, &y, 1, n);
    
    let pt_statistic = pt(STATISTIC)
    let nuevo_p_value = 2 * min(, df),
                         pt(STATISTIC, df, lower.tail=FALSE)))

    // P-value
    // Same behavior as Python Scipy's pearsonr method
    let x = 0.5 * (1.0 - r.abs());
    let p_value = 2.0 * beta_P(x, ab, ab);

    println!("{} | {}", r, p_value); r = -0.7426106572325057 | p-value = 0.2573893427674943
}
```

Note that in Rust the p-value is much different from the other two alternatives. What I'm missing? Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I was using some code from C++, others from R, and others from Scipy. I opted to follow the implementation of R's [cor.test method](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/library/stats/R/cor.test.R#L21) and the final code looked like this:

```rust
use rgsl::{
    randist::t_distribution::{tdist_P, tdist_Q},
    statistics::correlation,
};

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0];
    let y = vec![10.0, 9.0, 2.5, 6.0, 4.0];
    let n = x.len();
    let r = correlation(&x, 1, &y, 1, n);

    // P-value
    let df = (n - 2) as f64;
    let statistic = df.sqrt() * r / (1.0 - r.powi(2)).sqrt();
    let p_value = 2.0 * tdist_P(statistic, df).min(tdist_Q(statistic, df));
}
```